# Opensearchserver API with C#

Tags: c#, opensearch

I/m developing a winforms c# application and want to use openSearchServer API in my application.
Can you please provide some examples on how I can get the JSON/XML response for my search?
I'm currently using the below approach but can be made efficient

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9090/select?use=MSG&login=lorem&key=08762e43getye0042f875e86eaiu687f&qt=search&q="+searchTerm );
        string responseFromServer = GetQueryResults(request);

        // Parse XML Data

        string response = GetResultsFromXML(responseFromServer);
   private string GetQueryResults(WebRequest request)
    {
        //specify protcol
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.Headers.
        request.Method = "PUT";

        ////Get Request stream
        Stream datastream = request.GetRequestStream();


        datastream.Close();
        // Get response

        WebResponse respose = request.GetResponse();

        datastream = respose.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return responseFromServer;
    }

    private string GetResultsFromXML(string responseFromServer)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        #region XmlDocument
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();


        xdoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);


        XmlNodeList nodelist = xdoc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc");
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = (DataGridViewRow)dgvResults.Rows[0].Clone();
            foreach (XmlAttribute attrib in node.Attributes)
            {

                if (attrib.Name == "score")
                {
                    dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = attrib.Value;
                }
                else if (attrib.Name == "docId")
                {
                    dgvRow.Cells[1].Value = attrib.Value;
                }
                else if (attrib.Name == "pos")
                {
                    dgvRow.Cells[2].Value = attrib.Value;
                }

            }

            XmlNodeList elements = node.SelectNodes("snippet");
            foreach (XmlNode node_element in elements)
            {
                if (node_element.Attributes[0].Value == "title")
                {
                    dgvRow.Cells[3].Value = node_element.InnerText;
                }
            }
            dgvResults.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
        }
        #endregion




        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Also, the request is made using OpenSearchServer API version 1 as I cant get the API2 working.Any sample queries will be helpful as I could not find any  working exmaples.

Also tried executing examples as given in the documentation  (Version 2 API):

```
http://localhost:9090/services/rest/index/my_index/document?login=lorem&key=08762e43getye0042f875e86eaiu687f
```

and it throws a http 405 -Method not allowed error.  I am looking for implementing the restful JSON API of opensearchserver. in the existing code ( tried with API version 1 which returns the XML)
Any ideas??

Comment: Could you do an effort to improve your question? Making it more clear what you tried so far (Maybe show `GetQueryResults` and `GetResultsFromXml` so we can see what you mean by making it more efficient?)

Comment: @Krish, did you solve the issue? I'm in the same situation than you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use this query in a browser since it is a PUT request, not a GET request.

API V2 (Restful) uses different HTTP methods, whereas API V1 used only GET requests.

Try using for example extension POSTMAN for Chrome to test your different queries, it easily allow for sending PUT/POST/GET/DELETE requests with content and headers.

Regarding the C code I'm afraid I will not be able to help you precisely.

Regards,
Alexandre

Comment: Thanks Alexandre.I tried using POSTMAN and able to get the JSON results with PUT Request.However in POSTMAN I pass the parameters / query like {"query":"somevalueto search"} and the URL still remains same. How if i want to pass it programatically. Can you show me an example of how the URL looks / should be built?

Comment: Hi, you will not be able to run this query using only a browser :) Browser only make GET requests. You need to use a PUT here. You can do it programmatically, you just need to pass "{"query":"somevalueto search"}" in the body of the request . Code from your first question looked promising, but I'm not a c# expert.